# How can I get my linux PC to "advertise" itself for the scan-to-WSD feature of my HP ColorLaser MFP 178?

Tags: scanner

I have a used HP ColorLaser MFP 178 scanner/printer (connected to my home LAN) that I plan to use for scanning lots of documents. The printer has a feature called "Scan to WSD" where, after pressing a button on the device, it can scan and save the scanned document directly to a PC. I really like this feature, since it allows to scan multiple documents quickly without the need to do anything on the PC, I can put my scanner somewhere in my house and just scan.

For a Windows 10 laptop, I got this to work. After installing some HP software, the printer "discovers" the laptop and shows it as an option in the "Scan to WSD" menu.

So I had the idea to use my NAS (OpenMediaVault). It would be great if I could just go to my scanner, press the "Scan to WSD", select my NAS (always on) and scan directly there, without the need to ever start a laptop or interact with a PC at all. But I wasn't successful to make my printer recognize my NAS and show it as an option in the "Scan to WSD" menu.

I am able to run software, e.g. `xsane` or GIMP on my NAS and initiate a scan from there, also `airscan-discover` recognizes the scanner:

```
$ airscan-discover
[devices]
  HPC0180397DB46 (HP Color Laser MFP 178 179) = http://192.168.188.29:80/eSCL/, eSCL
  HPC0180397DB46 (HP Color Laser MFP 178 179) = https://192.168.188.29:443/eSCL/, eSCL
  HPC0180397DB46 (HP Color Laser MFP 178 179) = http://192.168.188.29:8018/wsd/scan, WSD
```

So apparently the connection between the scanner and the NAS works as expected, I am just missing something that "advertises" my NAS to the scanner in order to be recognized as a valid option for "Scan to WSD".

This [comment](https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan-unstable/issues/3) here from the maintainer of `airscan-discover` seems to confirm that some service is missing that

1. tells the scanner that my NAS is a valid "Scan to WSD" option
2. is constantly running on the NAS to react to incoming scanned documents.

Does anybody know if and how I can get this to work?

**EDIT:** I tried another approach, using [scanbd](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/scanbd.8.html) (a tool which tries to detect if any buttons on the "scanner" were pressed and can run scripts), which would allow me to trigger a scan on the NAS from the scanner, but unfortunately, my printer does not seem to have any buttons recognnized by `scanbd`:

```
$ scanimage -A
Output format is not set, using pnm as a default.

All options specific to device `smfp:net;192.168.188.29':
    --preview[=(yes|no)] [no]
        Request a preview-quality scan
  Image Quality:
    --mode Color - 16 Million Colors|Grayscale - 256 Levels|Black and White - Halftone|Black and White - Line Art [Color - 16 Million Colors]
        Set the color composition mode of the scanned image
    --resolution 75|100|150|200|300|600|1200dpi [300]
        Set the resolution of the scanned image
  Scan Area:
    --page-format Stateme|Stateme|A5|A5(Rota|B5(JIS)|Executi|A4|Letter|Custom [Lette]
        Set the paper format of the scanned page
    -l 0..216mm [0]
        Set left position of the scan area
    -t 0..297mm [0]
        Set top position of the scan area
    -x 0..216mm [215]
        Width of scan-area.
    -y 0..297mm [279]
        Height of scan-area.
```

Looks like I am stuck with WSD...